# How to save interest point in SURF feature?

Tags: emgucv, similarity, surf

I'm using Emgu CV's SURF feature to recognize similar objects in images. 
The image is drawn, showing all the key points found, in both images. The problem  is that the similar points are seen in the image.

How can I save those match points in a database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a class `SURF.cs` then write the following code in it:

```
        public void FindSURF(Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage)
    {
        VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
        SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);

        //extract features from the object image
        modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
        Matrix<float> modelDescriptors = surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(modelImage, null, modelKeyPoints);
    }
```

Then, in the `program.cs` write the following code:

```
                       SURF FindImageSURF = new SURF();

         string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\folderimages\");

        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
        {
            string path = filePaths[i];
            using (Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(path))
            {
                FindImageSURF.FindSURF(modelImage);
            }
        }
```